# Multiple the same form label in a page issue

Tags: html, forms, label

I have a multiple forms in one page. Each form has exactly the same content. But i encountered an issue regarding with my labels. I know that label "for" tag should be unique and pointed to the element id but I have to multiply the form for some reason.
Please refer to my code found in jsfiddle [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/QDf8P/)

```
<form>
<label for="option1">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="options">

<label for="option2">Option 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="options">

<label for="option3">Option 3</label>
<input type="radio" id="option3" name="options">
</form>

<!-- another form but the same content -->
<form>
<label for="option1">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="options">

<label for="option2">Option 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="options">

<label for="option3">Option 3</label>
<input type="radio" id="option3" name="options">
</form>​
```

Thanks

Comment: `for` does not have to be unique. `id` does. You can have multiple labels pointing to the same form control.

Answer (score 7):

Either:

- Generate a prefix that you apply to all the ids in a given instance of a form
- Don't use `for` or `id` and place the form controls *inside* the label elements.